# Hystrix-javanica @fallbackMethod Last Cached Response

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix

I'm looking to do something like the following:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "returnLastGoodCachedCopy")
void performRequest(String someArg) { 
    // Make HTTP request using RestTemplate configured with EHCache  
}

void returnLastGoodCachedCopy(String someArg) {
    // Return the last successful response 
}
```

For a little more background I am using Spring Boot, and setting up the `RestTemplate` like so to use EHCache:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}

@Bean
public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() {
    CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.custom()
            .setMaxCacheEntries(this.httpClientProperties.getMaxCacheEntries())
            .setMaxObjectSize(this.httpClientProperties.getMaxObjectSize())
            .setHeuristicCachingEnabled(this.httpClientProperties.getHeuristicLifetimeEnabled())
            .setHeuristicDefaultLifetime(this.httpClientProperties.getHeuristicLifetimeSeconds()).build();

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectTimeout(this.httpClientProperties.getConnectTimeout())
            .setSocketTimeout(this.httpClientProperties.getSocketTimeout()).build();

    Ehcache httpEhcache = (Ehcache) this.ehCacheManager.getCache(httpClientProperties.getCacheName())
            .getNativeCache();

    EhcacheHttpCacheStorage ehcacheHttpCacheStorage = new EhcacheHttpCacheStorage(httpEhcache);

    CloseableHttpClient cachingClient = CachingHttpClients.custom().setCacheConfig(cacheConfig)
            .setHttpCacheStorage(ehcacheHttpCacheStorage).setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

    return cachingClient;
}

private ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
    return factory;
}
```

So my one thought was to use the same request EHCache, but I'm not sure that's an appropriate solution considering that cache is based on cache-control headers, which I'd like to be separated from so I can return a valid response regardless if it is expired or not.

My other thought was to configure a separate EHCache cache, and store the responses myself, then I can access those more easily considering I set the format of the key and the value.

Before I go down this path I want to see if there is already anything built into Hystrix that handles this situation, or if there are any other recommended approaches.

Comment: I think there is nothing which you can really out of the box. I personally would create an own annotation that could encapsulate `@HystrixCommand` and `@Cacheable` or do the caching on your own. Then you'd just have to annotate this onto every method which you want to wrap. Would also have the benefit that you can use this for services that are not using the `RestTemplate`.

Comment: @Steve Hi, Did you get a chance to figure out what needs to be done to return the last successful response?